# How to improve garage floor look and color?

Tags: concrete, flooring, painting, floor, garage

Here is a image of my garage floor. 
[image]

**[Hi-Res Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvq8E.jpg)**

This is after a professional high pressure water cleaning contractor that used degreaser and bicarb soda chemicals to try to rid the floor of oil stains, rust stains and general garage abuse stains.

I have a function planned where I have 2 days of prep time. What are my options on making this floor look the best possible?

People will be walking on it, a car will be driven in and out of it repeatedly.

Have considered painting. Dry time not enough and the job should be good enough for future use.

Have also considered lino using double sided tape.

Budget is a concern too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outdoor carpet ~$6 a square yard.

[image: Outdoor carpet]

Most people think of the good ol' green stuff, but there are many styles to choose from nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Rust-Oleum Epoxy Shield](http://www.summitracing.com/parts/rll-225359?seid=srese1&gclid=CjkKEQjw5qmdBRCn--70gPSo074BEiQAJCe7zTZIdTc8SH6ichCoE3h0isI_t4ImM7AbKXB3wg_Rb9fw_wcB) on a few concrete applications and I have to say it may be the "cheap"/non-fancy alternative but it has handled soaking into the concrete (instead of other paints that only sat on top of concrete) to provide a little more protection.  I have bought the two part epoxy speckle kits and have never been happy after a few months.